# Move slider in Selenium Webdriver with Java and Firefox

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, slider, webdriver

I have a problem using Selenium Webdriver (version 2.32.0) and Firefox (21.0), trying to change the values on a slider.

I wrote a Java code like this:

```
private void selectGiftCardPrice() throws TestingException {
        try {
            WebElement slider = getDriver().findElement(
                    By.cssSelector("div.sliderHandle"));
            Actions move = new Actions(getDriver());
            move.dragAndDropBy(slider, 90, 0);
            move.build().perform();
            sleep(4000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(e);
            throw new TestingException("e");
        }
```

I tried out every code I found on the Web, every change, and it still does not work. It does not show any problem, just finds the element, and does nothing. Any idea what it is, or what can I do?

**EDIT from comment:**

I finally made it working with [jQuery slider demo](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/slider/multiple-vertical.html)

```
driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/slider/multiple-vertical.html");
WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[1]/a[contains(@class,'ui-slider-handle')]"));‌
```

But it is still not working for me with [jQuery UI Slider demo page](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) using Xpath `//div[@id='slider']/a`. What is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried this: `move.dragAndDropBy(slider, 90, 0).build().perform();` ? I've noticed a few times that when using the `Actions()` class its best to try and keep all actions as part of the same chain. Interrupting the chain and have 'odd' effects.

Comment: Yes, I did and it was still not working, :-(.

Comment: Piece of html, please. With slider and input

Comment: I finally made it works with the Web page driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/slider/multiple-vertical.html"); and the WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[1]/a[contains(@class,'ui-slider-handle')]"));, but it is still not working for me with the example page  http://jqueryui.com/slider/ and the Xpath "//div[@id='slider']/a", FireBug either finds the Xpath with FirePath, but for sure it is right. What is the problem?

Comment: Correct the xpath as  //div[@id='slider']/span instead of  //div[@id='slider']/a

Answer (score 1):

This code works absolutely fine for me. 
program handles slider of website : [Homeshope18.com](http://homeshope18.com)
Check it out:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.homeshop18.com/fashion-jewellery/category:15143/filter_Theme:%28%22Traditional+Wear%22+%22Cuff+%26+Kada%22+%22Daily+Wear%22+%22Maang+Tikka%22+%22Openable+Round%22+%22Round%22+%22Openable+Oval%22%29/sort:Popularity/inStock:true/?it_category=HP&it_action=JW-HPSP01&it_label=HP-HPSP01-131021235900-PD-JW-ZC-VK-SC_DiwaliFestWeddingJewellery&it_value=0");

WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='slider-range']/a[1]"));
Thread.sleep(3000);

Actions moveSlider = new Actions(driver);
Action action = moveSlider.dragAndDropBy(slider, 30, 0).build();

action.perform();
```

Comment: Nice. It's working but I cannot control the number of units to move.

Answer (score 0):

Using Actions class, firs use `clickAndHold("WebElemnt");`

Then to move horizontally we need to move in the Y direction of the screen so we can use `movebyoffset`, i.e X-axis: 0 & Y axis: 40px

To move vertically we need to move in the X direction of the screen so we can use `movebyoffset`, i.e X-axis: 40px & Y axis: 0

The sample code would be :

```
Actions slider=new Actions(driver);
slider.clickAndHold("WebElemnt");
slider.movebyoffset(0,40).build.perform();
```